# Why this approach works for solving USAMTS's number theory problem?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, ceiling-and-floor-functions

This is the first problem of [USAMTS $1998$ Round $1$](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c4672_1998_usamts_problems)

> Several pairs of positive integers $(m ,n )$ satisfy the condition
> $19m + 90 + 8n = 1998$. Of these, $(100, 1 )$ is the pair with the
> smallest value for $n$. Find the pair with the smallest value for $m$.

Users on AOPS solved it with different approaches [here](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h427587p2421581). This is @RedFireTruck's answer:

> $$(100-8\lfloor\frac{100}8\rfloor,1+19\lfloor\frac{100}8\rfloor)=(4,229)$$

I don't understand why this approach works. It seems they used the fact that $(100,1)$ is a pair with smallest $n$ then subtracted $8\lfloor\frac{100}8\rfloor$ from the first number and added $19\lfloor\frac{100}8\rfloor$ to second one to get the result. Can you please explain how it works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the Diophantine equation $ax+by=c$.
If $\gcd(a,b)=1$ and if one of the solution is $(x_0,y_0)$, then the general solution is given by $(x_0+bk,y_0-ak)$

**Proof**

> Let $i$ be the smallest positive integersuch that $x_0+i$ satisfies the
> Diophantine equation.
> Let the solution pair be $(x_0+i,y_0-j)$.
> We have $ax_0+ai+by_0-bj=c$
> $\implies ai=bj$.
>  $i$ is minimum when $i=b$.$\implies j=a$
> $(x_0+b,y_0-a)$ is the solution which has the  smallest value of $x$ greater than $x_0$.
> Continuing the same way we can prove that $(x_0+bk,y_0-ak)$ is the general solution